# Passing data to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I scraped data from Json and containing arrays in queryLat/queryLng after that I create another function initMap also bind it to google script. But I having hard to time passing queryLat and queryLng into initMap. "queryLat is not defined" pops up. How I can pass those to initMap.

```
    var queryLat = [];
    var queryLng = [];

    @foreach($estates as $est)
        var result = $.getJSON({
                url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
            });

        result.done(function(data) {

            queryLat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            queryLng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        });
    @endforeach


    function initMap()
    {
        var options =
            {
                zoom : 10,
                center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
            }

        var map  = new
            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);


        for (var i = 0; i < queryLat.length; i++)
        {
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                position: {lat: queryLat[i], lng: queryLng[i]} ,
                map: map
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do not  define those variables again inside @foreach

Comment: `queryLat` and `queryLng` overwriting the values on last index result of `$estates`. If you need last result, do not use loop. One more thing, your map loading async, may your $getJSON not done before this, which affect to the assign null values as `lat` and `lng`

Comment: thanks a lot already solved but How can I iterate markers? @Sachink

Comment: make `queryLat` and `queryLng` as array. and loop it for marker :)     `for (var i = 0; i < queryLat.length; i++) {
    
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: queryLat[i], lng: queryLng[i]} ,
                map: map
            });
    
        }`

Comment: I did the same thing before :) but not worked actually no error in the console but there is no marker in the map too. If I dont use for then I get one marker though : )) I updated the codes could you check it please? @Sachink

Comment: Why do you cross post the same question with different accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple markers if you are defining arrays globally then you have to push your lat and long values in array and also need to update the marker variable to display diferent markers.. Hope it helps you to get the multiple markers.

var queryLat = [];
    var queryLng = [];

```
@foreach($estates as $est)
    var result = $.getJSON({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
        });

    result.done(function(data) {

        queryLat.push(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        queryLng.push(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
    });
@endforeach

function initMap()
{
    var options =
        {
            zoom : 10,
            center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
        }

    var map  = new
        google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);


    for (var i = 0; i < queryLat.length; i++)
    {
        var new_marker_str = "newMarker"+i;
        new_marker_str = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            position: {lat: queryLat[i], lng: queryLng[i]} ,
            map: map
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: okay the problem is sometimes, no marker, sometimes one or two markers coming on the map when i refresh it :))

Comment: That is basically dependent on your API response from where you are getting data of lat lng from google by sending your address with request..

Answer (score 0):

You Should define your variables queryLat and queryLng globally where your script starts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var queryLat;
var queryLng;
@foreach($estates as $est)
    var result = $.getJSON({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
        });

    result.done(function(data) {
       queryLat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
       queryLng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    });
@endforeach


function initMap()
{
    var options =
        {
            zoom : 12,
            center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
        }

    var map  = new
        google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

    var marker = new
        google.maps.Marker
        ({
           position: {lat: queryLat, lng: queryLng},
           map: map
        });
}
```

Comment: and by the way how can I itarate markers? because query's are array, could you please sow me that_/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
```

You have enclosed the string with apostrophes, but the string contains apostrophes too.

Use this instead:

```
url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}"
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but no effects still no marker.